# how to get $_POST[] value instantly after on select box change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get $_POST value instantly after changing select option and without submitting the form.

```
             <select name="cat_id"  class="form-control" onChange="this.form.submit();" style="width:300px;">

    <?php
    $sql_menu_1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM mdg_products where up_id = 0 and parentid = 0");
while($row_menu_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_menu_1))
{
echo '<option 
  value="'.$row_menu_1["id"].'">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row_menu_1["name"].'</option>';
}
    ?>
    </select>
```

I am doing this with onchange="this.form.submit" and catch value in $_POST array but I want to do this without submitting the form on each option change

Comment: You've put the `AJAX` tag on your post... that's what you need.

Comment: I would suggest using ajax if you've used it before. You tagged this question with it correctly.

Comment: for a select, you can check the [jQuery .change() function](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

Without submitting the form, you cannot  have `$_POST`. You can however get the value in a Javascript variable.In that case, no need to use `onChange="this.form.submit();"` Instead use the following js snippet:

```
     var selected_value='';// this is the value you want to get.
     $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#cat_id").change(function(){

        selected_value=$(this).val().trim();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can use hidden input box and set there the value but the most recommend is use jQuery functions to do that